# How do I convert just a single character in a string to an uppercase letter?

Tags: c

I'm writing a program and I've captured a substring. I want to declare a pointer to the first element of that substring AND if that first element happens to be a lowercase letter, I want to send it to a makeshift toupper function (as I cannot use any libraries aside from stdio.h) and then return that element

This is the code I have for the toupper function, which I've titled firstletterUpper:

```
char firstletterUpper(char *fc) //fc stands for first character
{
    if(*fc >= 'a' && *fc <= 'z')
    {
        fc = fc-32;
    }
}
```

And this is what I tried to do to make a pointer to the first element of a substring I made as well as how I tried to print it:

```
char *str1fc = &subStr1[0];

    printf("str1fc BEFORE firstletterUpper: %c\n", *str1fc);

    if(str1firstUpper = 0)
    {
        firstletterUpper(str1fc);
    }

    printf("str1fc AFTER firstletterUpper: %c\n", *str1fc);
```

fyi: str1firstUpper is the flag I made to determine if the first element in the string is Uppercase

This is my output:

```
Enter two strings seperated by a space: hello hello
str1fc BEFORE firstletterUpper: h
str1fc AFTER firstletterUpper: h
```

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/ -- can you figure it out by looking at this?

Comment: Your `firstletterUpper` function doesn't return any value. It computes a value and then throws that value away.

Comment: Your "toupper" function won't compile because you have no `return`. Do you want it to modify the original string? If so, you want [cleaned up]: `*fc = (*fc - 'a') + 'A'`]. If you want to return the value and leave the string unchanged, you shouldn't use `char *` as the argument, but [cleaned up] `int` with `int` return type.

Comment: `*fc ^= 32;` to toggle bit-6 (the lowercase bit in 7-bit ASCII) off. You could do `char *firstcharUpper (char *fc) { if (fc && 'a' <= *fc && *fc <= 'z') *fc ^= 32; return fc; }` By returning `fc` you provide the convenience of using the function with your output, e.g. `puts (firstcharUpper (str));`

Answer (score 2):

In the function firstletterUpper, `fc` is a pointer to a char. Thus, the value of `fc` is a memory location. The actual value is given by `*fc`. So, when you're doing `fc = fc-32;`, you're actually modifying the address `fc` points to rather than the actual character value.

Instead you want to modify the character `fc` points to:

```c
char firstletterUpper(char *fc) //fc stands for first character
{
    if (*fc >= 'a' && *fc <= 'z')
    {
        *fc = *fc - 'a' + 'A';
    }
}
```

Use the character constants directly to show your intent. `32` is a magic number that confuses anyone not knowing about ASCII. *(Note: There are more character encodings than ASCII, and not all of them have all the letters in sequence.)*

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `#include <ctype.h>` in order to use the function `toupper( )`. This will take a lowercase character and covert it to an uppercase character without having to worry about ASCII values. In the context of your code you need to dereference the pointer and then covert that value to an uppercase character. Try something like this:

```
char firstLetterUpper(char *fc) {
    if (islower(*fc))
        *fc = toupper(*fc);
    return fc;
}
```

Note that `islower( )` is also a function included in the header file that determines if a character is lowercase.

Answer (score -1):

When you compare things in C, you should always use double '='. If you don't use double '=', C interprets it as an assignment, which is always true and changes the value of the variable you are trying to compare (in this case it changes `str1firstUpper` to 0.

please, review this part of your code:

```
if(str1firstUpper = 0)
{
    firstletterUpper(str1fc);
}
```

a better approach should do this: (note the double '=' sign in the *if* comparison)

```
if(str1firstUpper == 0)
{
    firstletterUpper(str1fc);
}
```

Another important thing to notice is when you print a string, you should always use `%s` instead of `%c`, which only prints one character.

**WRONG:**

`printf("str1fc BEFORE firstletterUpper: %c\n", *str1fc);`

`printf("str1fc AFTER firstletterUpper: %c\n", *str1fc);`

**RIGHT:**

`printf("str1fc AFTER firstletterUpper: %s\n", *str1fc);`

`printf("str1fc AFTER firstletterUpper: %c\n", *str1fc);`

Wish you the best luck! happy coding!

Comment: While true, this does not answer the question. This is not the issue. Your answer should be a comment.

Comment: I don't have reputation for a comment :(
But maybe the printf bug should solve his problems

Comment: he should also fix the bugs the other people found. like the lack of a 'return' and the pointer bug

Comment: Also he uses the `tr1firstUpper`variable as a flag. What could happen is that he starts to compute the `firstLetterUpper` function even to uppercase letters because of this comparison, and that changes the letter he is pointing to.

Comment: another thing that could happen is that if he is inside a while loop, sometimes the reassignment of `str1firstUpper` in a comparison can lead to a wrong comparison in the future that can be harder to detect

Comment: this is my first answer in StackOverflow

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you don't have the reputation for comments, then gain some. But you won't get any if you're answering ... well ... like this. Please be patient! See if there is something you can actually answer.